# .NET CORE and ADFS no Claims Available

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, adfs, ws-federation

Migrating to .NET Core 3 from a 4.6 project and I'm not 100% sure I am implementing things properly.

I followed the steps in this article, making sure to configure startup.cs following the code sample under the "Use WS-Federation without ASP.NET Core Identity" section. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Login seems to be working in that I'm redirected to MS login and sent back to my app with the expected cookies, for example MSISAuthenticated. But, user.identity.isauthenticated is always false and I have no claims available. Is this expected behavior? Perhaps I'm not configuring things properly? Ideally I'd like to be able to check if a user is authenticated and access the claims.

I've come across a number of articles about adding policies based on groups, but how would [Authorize (Policy="SomeGroup")] even work if no claims are available?

ConfigureServices Code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msNDi.png)

Configure Code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yurSP.png)

Controller Action:

```html
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            ViewBag.Claims = identity.Claims;

            return View();
        }
```

View Code:

```html
@using System.Security.Claims;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = (IEnumerable<Claim>)ViewBag.Claims;
}

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Successful Sign On!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>WS Federation Services Claims</h2>
            @foreach (Claim claim in claims)
            {
                <p>
                    <b>@(claim.Type.ToString())</b>
                    <br />
                    @(claim.Value.ToString()) (type: @(claim.ValueType.ToString()))
                    <hr />
                </p>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>SSO Test</h1>
        <p class="lead">To sign in using Microsoft's single sign-on service, click the button below.</p>
        <p><a href="/account/signin" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign in &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Could you share samples that could reproduce your issue?How did you configure in Startup.cs?

Comment: Thanks, I added screens shots for ConfigureServices and Configure methods.

Comment: Did you try to set `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseAuthorization();`?And how did you judge the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`?Share a sample code would be more helpful to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I added a snippet from the return page view, which includes the check for isAuthenticated. I did actually try moving app.UseAuthentication() before app.UseAuthorization(), but that made no difference.

Comment: I think you need to store the individual claims returned from the provider, this can be intercepted during the `OnSecurityTokenValidated` event. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.wsfederation.wsfederationevents?view=aspnetcore-3.0 for more information.

Comment: I've added that event, along with every other event available and none of them are hit after the redirect from a successful login.

Comment: Turns out we're on ADFS 2012. Need to be on 2016 for CORE support. Thanks for the help though!
https://forums.asp.net/t/2123040.aspx?Adfs+Authentication

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the fact is that you are not send the desired ResourceUrl to ADFS. Then ADFS considers the default resource and issues a token without claims.
See more info on 3 step in "High level AD FS authentication flow"

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-concepts)

> AD FS identifies the resource which the client wants to access through
>   the resource parameter passed in the auth request. If using MSAL
>   client library, then resource parameter is not sent. Instead the
>   resource url is sent as a part of the scope parameter: scope =
>   [resource url]//[scope values e.g., openid].